# Approximating symmetric matrices by symmetrized low rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

Fix an integer $k$, and suppose $M$ is a real symmetric $n\times n$ matrix admitting a decomposition:
$$
M = A + A^t + B
$$
with $\mathrm{rank}(A)=k$ and:
$$
\|B\|_2 \ll \lambda_{1}(M_{|\mathrm{range}(A)})
$$
where $\lambda_{1}(M_{|\mathrm{range}(A)})$ is the smallest singular value of the quadratic form $M$ restricted to the range of $A$.

In particular, we see that: 
$$\|M_{|\mathrm{range}(A)^\perp}\|_2 \leq \|B\|_2 \ll \lambda_{1}(M_{|\mathrm{range}(A)})$$
If $M$ is positive semidefinite, using perturbation arguments for eigenspaces, this implies that a decomposition as above can be found by diagonalizing $M$.

However, if $M$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues, this argument does not work and diagonalizing $M$ doesn't seem to help. Is there an efficient way to find a decomposition as above in this case?

Comment: Is the $B=0$ case any easier?

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure. It doesn't seem significantly easier at first sight at least.